# Convince TypeScript that Vue 3 template ref is available in onMounted

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to work with an HTML canvas in a TypeScript Vue 3 component (Composition API).

The issue I am facing is that in an `onMounted` hook callback, TypeScript is telling me that the value of my template ref could be undefined even though I know it will not be by the time that `onMounted` fires. Is there anything I can do to convince TypeScript that it is not undefined and let me call methods on it?

Currently, I have wrapped it in an `if`-statement type guard style, but I am looking for a better way.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

const canvasElem = ref<HTMLCanvasElement>();

let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;

onMounted(() => {
  if (canvasElem.value !== undefined) {
    ctx = canvasElem.value.getContext("2d");
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <canvas ref="canvasElem" height="700" width="900"></canvas>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```js
onMounted(() => {
  ctx = canvasElem.value!.getContext("2d");
});
```

[demo 1](https://tsplay.dev/m0y0oW)

Or [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) combined with [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to default to `null` (to satisfy the type of `ctx`):

```js
onMounted(() => {
  ctx = canvasElem.value?.getContext("2d") ?? null;
});
```

[demo 2](https://tsplay.dev/wEvqvN)